# Number of ways to select N sets out of M sets, plus 1 item from each set

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have `M` sets with a different number of items from each:

`e.g. [a b c] [d e] [f g h] [i j k l] [m] [n o p q] ... [w x]`

I need to select `N` of these sets, and one item from each set:

`e.g. If N = 3:
[a d f]
[a e f]
[a e h]
[a e i]
[d f l]
...`

How many possible ways are there of doing this?

Comment: Let me ask you a question.. How many combinations/sets do you expect from having 3 elements namely A,B, and C?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? If there are 3 elements, then there are 3C3 + 3C2 + 3C1 possible subsets. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I am confused so let's take a small example. Like if you have A,B elements. Possible ways would be {A},{B},{A,B},{B,A} = 4??

Comment: I see. The input is a set of sets. So suppose there are three sets (M = 3): {a,b,c}, {d,e}, and {f}, and I want to select two sets (N = 2), then here are all the combinations:

{a, d}, {a, e}, {b , d}, {b, e}, {c, d}, {c, e}, {a, f}, {b, f}, {c, f}, {d, f}, {e, f}

= 11 combinations

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_{i}$ denote the $i^{th}$ set out of $M$ and |$S_{i}$| denote the size of $S_{i}$. We assume all sets are disjoint.

Since the number of total elements and specific set sizes arent defined, this answer will be very abstract. You need to sum the ways of picking an element from each set across each distinct possible selection of N sets.

Let $B_{j}$ denote the $j^{th}$ string out of ${M\choose N}$ binary strings with M digits containing N 1s.
Let $B_{j,i}$ denote the $i^{th}$ binary digit in the $j^{th}$ string.

## $\sum_{j=1}^{M\choose N} \prod_{i=1}^{M} B_{j,i}* |S_{i}|$

Comment: That formula is correct, but it takes exponential time for me to calculate it. Is there a polynomial time algorithm?